# matterJS rendering to canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, game-physics, matter.js

Im trying to use matterJS and render it to specific canvas in my layout but I can't manage it.

This the the JS:

```
window.addEventListener("load",init);
    function init(){

    var canvas = document.getElementById('matterJS');
    var width = 100,
        height = 100;

    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height; 
        // Matter.js - http://brm.io/matter-js/

        // Matter module aliases
        var Engine = Matter.Engine,
            World = Matter.World,
            Body = Matter.Body,
            Composites = Matter.Composites,
            MouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint;

        // create a Matter.js engine
        var engine = Engine.create({
          render: {
            element: document.body,
            canvas: canvas,
            options: {
              width: 100,
              height: 100,                  
              showAngleIndicator: true,
              showVelocity: true,
              wireframes: false
            }
          }
        });

        // add a mouse controlled constraint
        var mouseConstraint = MouseConstraint.create(engine);
        World.add(engine.world, mouseConstraint);

        // add a Newton's Cradle (using the Composites factory method!)
        var cradle = Composites.newtonsCradle(280, 150, 5, 30, 200);
        World.add(engine.world, cradle);

        // offset the first body in the cradle so it will swing
        Body.translate(cradle.bodies[0], { x: -180, y: -100 });

        // run the engine
        Engine.run(engine);
   }
```

in my html im doing this:

```
<canvas class="matterJS"></canvas>
```

I don't get any error but nothing is rendered either.. I think this should work. But why it doesn't?

I can only render the outcome when im creating the engine like this:

```
var engine = Engine.create(document.getElementById('matterJS'),{
                options: {
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,                  
                  showAngleIndicator: true,
                  showVelocity: true,
                  wireframes: false
              }
            });
```

Comment: You have `class="matterJS"` on your `<canvas>` but the call you're using to retrieve it is `document.getElementById("matterJS")`. You probably meant `<canvas id="matterJS">`. Debug this by determining if the value returned by your `getElementById` is an object rather than null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now is solved like this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('matterJS');
var width = 800,
    height = 800;

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height; 
    // Matter.js - http://brm.io/matter-js/

    // Matter module aliases
    var Engine = Matter.Engine,
        World = Matter.World,
        Body = Matter.Body,
        Composites = Matter.Composites,
        MouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint;

    // create a Matter.js engine
    var engine = Engine.create(canvas, {
        options: {
          width: 1000,
          height: 1000,                 
          showAngleIndicator: true,
          showVelocity: true,
          wireframes: false
      }
    });
```

Comment: I can't get this to work. The console shows: Matter.js: – "Engine.create: engine.render is deprecated (see docs)"

Comment: It isn't necessary to generate the canvas dynamically like this. Your call was failing because of a missing id on the canvas, but otherwise it's perfectly fine to use `document.getElementById` (and that family of functions) to find the canvas node to pass to MJS.